# Solution for image ratio in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, image

Here's the problem, in brief:

We have a responsive layout which scales our images depending on the screen width. For narrow / small screens we adjust to a two column layout; for wider screens or landscape tablets we can comfortably show four columns. All pretty standard.

The images are defined to be 100% of the width of containing element, and have a height of auto. This works fine in all browsers from IE7+.

The problem is that on page load the browser **has no idea what height to expect the images to be**. Thus there's a lot of reflow/redrawing as each image is loaded. In fact they're mostly square, but there's no way to hint to the browser the ratio of any of them. Because we serve a lot of images, this causes the page rendering to slow down. On a device with lower processing power, e.g. old iPhone, I'm guessing it gobbles up a lot of unnecessary CPU too.

A possible javascript solution would be to inject a rule into the css based on the page size; this will probably involve the entire page being redrawn though. It's not ideal.

My question is: **is there an elegant solution at hinting at the aspect ratio of an image**, thus allowing the page 'shape' to be more-or-less correct before image load, when using responsive (percentage-width-scaled) images.

Demonstration page here: http://www.partyark.co.uk/christmas-presents.html - try resizing the screen to see the images shrinking/growing. Min size is 145px, max 200px.

Comment: Could this tutorial be of any help?
http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [pure CSS technique](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video) first described by Thierry Koblentz. It's based on a wrapper with `position: relative`, zero height, and `padding-bottom` with a percentage size. The percentages of paddings apply to the width of the containing block, so you can achieve arbitrary aspect ratios with fluid layouts. Then you can put your image inside this wrapper, absolutely positioned, with 100% width and height. Example for 4:3 aspect ratio:

```
.wrapper-with-intrinsic-ratio {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; /* results in 4:3 aspect ratio */
    height: 0;
}

.element-to-stretch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Although this works well, there are certain limitations. But still, a lot better than nothing! After a lot of experimenting, I simply inserted a non-semantic block element within the image-containing elements, and 'squared' it (or whatever ratio I need) using the above technique.

Now the page loads in more-or-less the shape it needs to be before images, which is what I needed. So thanks.